# Are variables declared inside "with" statement local?

Tags: python

I was reading a question in StackOverflow where the user applied the "with" statement twice in a row, pipelining the results from a variable declared inside the first with statement into the second. Like so (simple example):

```
with open('first_file.txt', 'r') as f:
   loaded_file = f.readlines()
   #...Prepare a csv file somehow - loaded_file is not declared outside with...

with open("second_file.csv", "w") as f:
   for line in loaded_file:
      f.write(line+"\n")
```

Considering variable scopes, why does it work?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, "with" statements **does not** create a new scope.

The "With" statement is a resource developed by the Python Dev team to generalize a common (and heavily recommended) practice of closing opened resources even after an exception ocurred. Imagine the following situation:

```
try:
   f = open('file.txt', 'w')
   #Do some processing that can raise exceptions and leave 'f' open, eventually locking the file or having trash data loaded into RAM.
   #To avoid this situation, a mindful developer will do the following:
finally:
   f.close()
```

It gets verbose easily.

To solve the problem, python dev team proposed the use of some *dunder* methods which encapsule this process: __enter__() and __exit__() - these are invoked "under the hood" when you use a "with" statement.

You can even implement them in your own classes!

```
class controlled_execution:
    def __enter__(self):
        set things up
        return thing
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        tear things down
with controlled_execution() as thing:
    some code
```

In the end, a with statement, even though there's identation, is not a separate block of code. It is just **an ellegant try...finaly block**. It abstracts a "contained" piece of code.

This can be easily comprehended by looking at a try...except statement with variables declared inside the try:

```
x = 10
try:
    y = load_using_failable_function()
    z = 5
except FunctionFailureException:
    y = 10
#If you treat it properly, there's nothing wrong with doing:
x = x + y + z
```

I hope it is clear to anyone else looking for this reason.

Consulted websites:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/

https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Can you please add an answer "yes" or "not" to the question in the title "Are variables declared inside "with" statement local?"

Answer (score 3):

Only *one* statement creates a new scope: the `def` statement. Any other assignment creates a name that is local to the current function body.

The exceptions are:

- A name declared `global` refers to the (module) global scope rather than the local function body.
- A name declared `nonlocal` refers to the name defined in the closest containing function scope (or global scope if no other name is found)
- The Python interpreter itself can define names.

In your example, `f` is either a local variable or a global, depending on the scope where the `with` statement occurs. In no way is `f` local to any other particular statement.

Comment: Excelent addition. Provides further generalization to the answer.